# PDF French document R

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining, french

I work now with Rstudio version 3.4.3 and I tried to analyze a PDF document in French language using package *tm*.

My problem is that even I specify the language of the document with this command `my_pdf <- readPDF (control = list (text = "- layout")) (elem = list (uri = "C: /Users/lo/Desktop/Eau/Catalogs.pdf", language = "fr"))`. Some words are not well written, for example I find instead of the word "nourrice" the word "nourric" and instead "description" the word "descript".

Do you have any idea how i can solve that?

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is not related to French language, this is something that can happen when reading pdf (open a pdf and manually copy the text, you'll often see that some words are cut).

Comment: Try reading the pdf with `pdftools::pdftext()` and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: thank you very much for your help the terms are now correctly displayed using this function pdftext (). but when I try the text cleaning command for example docs <- pdf_text("C:/Users/lo/Desktop/Eau/Catalogues.pdf")
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)  
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("french"))

Comment: he shows me the following error
Error in UseMethod ("tm_map", x):
   no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"